# netsuite - inline html

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to use a custom column as a hyperlink to a external site. Meaning,

In PO detail page, I want to add a custom column and I want the value of it to have the following HTML content.

```
<a href="www.google.com">Try Google</a>
```

So when I go to the PO detail page I want to have a link to `google.com`.

How can I do this? I tried this as Inline HTML, Free-form Text and Rich text. none of them gave me a link.

Comment: I use google.com as a example value. In reallity I have a external PDF file to be open... Please HELP...!!!

Comment: If you want a hyperlink then why don't you just create a transaction column of type hyperlink and just put `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: Thanks Rockstar. When I User hyperlink it wont allow me to edit that field. I try to set a value from a php toolkit. Response was success but from NetSuite interface, still my field value is empty.

Comment: First try to put your value manually and see is it accepting your value or not.

Comment: It is not :(. When I go to edi, it is not even showing that field as editable.

Comment: then you might have created an inline field change it to normal

Comment: You mean a Inline HTML field?

Answer (score 1):

I found 1 way of doing this using .

```
 1. I added a Inline HTML field.
 2. I added the default value for that as a <iframe> block which sends data to my service point.
 3. In the service point I created the link (<a>) neede for that PO and print it.
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and finally found the answer. You need to create a field as Inline HTML and then enclose the link and the url in single quotes, concatenating with double pipes:

```
'<a href="' || 'https://google.com/search?q=' || {entityid} || '">Search Google</a>'
```

More help can be found here:
http://www.netsuiterp.com/2019/06/highlighting-url-link-custom-field.html